# How do Instant-On CFLs work?

Tags: compact-fluorescent-lamp

ProLume makes CFLs. I can't tell a difference between them and incandescents, and I'm pretty picky about this. I'm sure there is some 2 minute window where the light produced increases, but the point is that when I hit the switch, there is light, not 200ms later.

How do they do this? Do they maintain a certain charge in the gas so the arc forms more quickly? Does this waste energy?

Answer (score 1):

The CFLs, in general, have an SMPS inside. The input power (either 110 V or 230 V) is converted to DC by rectifiers and filters. The DC is then switched at higher frequencies (e.g. 15 kHz or 40 kHz) AC to run the florescent lamp. That is where the trick is.

The HF oscillator secondary would develop a very high voltage if open circuited. The florescent lamp needs a higher voltage to start, but normal operation is at a much lower voltage. On the other hand, the lamp presents almost an open circuit at the start.

When these two are put together, the high open circuit voltage of the HF oscillator secondary triggers the gas discharge. The lamp starts and presents the load to the HF oscillator and the voltage comes down to the normal operating voltage.

The older designs of CFLs could've used either separate HV sections for starting and operation or voltage multipliers. I saw at least one CFL with separate HV secondaries. In these cases, one part of the circuit builds the ionizing voltage to start the lamp, while the other part provides power for normal operation. In such designs, the time required for building ionizing voltage may be noticeable. So, the light output is a little bit delayed behind the mains switching on.

This is the basic principle, as far I understand. There could be variations in the implementations, though.

In conclusion: no - it should not waste energy. The gas is ionized only during the start-up. The energy consumption might spike a little bit during start-up, but it should only be for a few milliseconds, if any.

Comment: can you clarify how instant-on CFLs are different?

Comment: ok, rereading his answer, I think he's saying the AC used to drive the CFL is higher in an instant-On CFL than a normal CFL; and possibly higher energizing voltage. If his "or" in between "15KHz" and "40KHz" were a "vs." we would be less confused. I'd still like to know how different the oscillator frequencies are between the two

Comment: I updated the answer with a little more detail. Please note, the AC is not higher, the frequency of the AC is higher. Also, the SMPS may operate at 15KHz (old designs) or 40KHz (modern designs). The benefits & trade-offs of these SMPS designs are beyond scope of this question. So, it should be read as SMPS frequency (15KHz or 40KHz) vs. Mains frequency (60Hz or 50Hz). I do not know of any relation between the SMPS frequencies and the impact on the start-up delay.

Answer (score 1):

The **higher** (internal) voltage and frequency **cause the gas to ionize faster** than the "normal" 120v 60Hz supply.  This causes the instant-on property of the CFLs.  How this is done, is explained by @Vasu.

Answer (score 0):

The CFL is simply startet with a much higher voltage. There is not too much extra energy required to do that but a bit of tricky electronics.

Comment: The tricky part is exactly what we wanted to know.